# How do Isochron Scepter and the Fuse mechanic interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The split cards in the expansion set [Dragon's Maze](http://www.magicspoiler.com/dragons-maze/) contain a new mechanic "Fuse". This mechanic allows you to cast both sides of the spell, a new option for cards of this type.

[Isochron Scepter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Isochron%20Scepter) allows you to imprint any instant card with casting cost 2 or less, and then produce copies of that card once per turn.

The interaction of Isochron Scepter and instant split cards is a highly useful one, in that you can imprint a split card providing one side meets the requirements of Isochron Scepter, and then cast either side of the card using Isochron Scepter's linked ability.

**The fuse mechanic allows you to cast both sides of the card. How does this mechanic interact with Isochron Scepter?** This is relevant so far to [Turn // Burn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369080) and [Far // Away](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369042).

Comment: I recognize it may not be possible to answer this question correctly until the official rules are released, however I am sure it is one that will be asked.

Comment: Are you asking specifically whether Isochron would let you cast both sides of the card for 2 mana?

Comment: I am going to upvote this. Very good question.

Comment: @SocioMatt Yes - specifically whether fuse allows you to cast both sides using Isochron Sceptre's ability. I know already that you can for example cast Away for 2 mana due to being split with Far.

Comment: @Rawrgramming: By the way, one of the reasons for a hold on official rules at most sites is to ease quoting the relevant rule, in this case the exact mechanism through which the reminder text is enforced.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot use Fuse.

The reminder text reads "You may cast one or both halves of this card from your **hand**." The scepter allows you to cast a copy of the card from Exile. That it's not a card may or may not be relevant, but the addition of "from your hand" will surely be present in the rules, so it's pretty clear that Fuse cannot be used here.

As such, it's as if you were casting a regular split card. You can cast either side (even if the mana cost of that side is more than two), but not both.

---

**UPDATE**: The rules have been released, and the "from your hand" is indeed present in them.

> 702.101a Fuse is a static ability found on some split cards (see rule 708, "Split Cards") that applies while the card with fuse is in a player’s hand. If a player casts a split card with fuse from his or her hand, the player may choose to cast both halves of that split card. This choice is made before putting the split card with fuse onto the stack. The resulting spell is a fused split spell.
>
> 702.101b A fused split spell has two sets of characteristics and one converted mana cost. The converted mana cost of the spell is a number equal to the total amount of mana in its two mana costs, regardless of color.
>
> 702.101c The total cost of a fused split spell includes the mana cost of each half. (See rule 601.2e.)
>
> 702.101d As a fused split spell resolves, the controller of the spell follows instructions of the left half and then follows the instructions of the right half.

Comment: Nice catch on reminder text. +1

Comment: I am very tempted to agree with you, and I think this is likely going to end up being the final word on this interaction, however there are a number of instances where reminder text can be a little misleading, so I will hold off on accepting for now (until the full rules for this mechanic are released)

Comment: There's no reason to specify "from your hand" if it wasn't limited to castings from your hand. It would be shorter not to specify this limitation.

Comment: The rule change have been released. My answer is confirmed.

Answer (score 9):

[This post](http://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/47496931426/if-you-copy-a-split-card-with-isochron-scepter-would) on Tumblr from a judge makes this pretty clear:

> ***YOU CAN ONLY CAST BOTH HALVES OF A SPELL WITH FUSE WHEN YOU CAST IT FROM YOUR HAND.***
>   
> Sorry for having to yell there, but people don’t seem to be getting that point, so I have to keep reinforcing it.
>  Also, you can cast either half of a split card that’s imprinted on Isochron Scepter. Just not both.

As ikegami said, this is because of the clause in the Fuse reminder text that says "from your hand." So after you imprint it, you can use either side like with other split cards, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this thread is a number of years old, and I wouldn't normally necro such a thread. However, because I just had the same question myself now with new Split cards about to be released in the Return to Ravnica set in October 2018, I thought to check the Gatherer rulings on Isochron Scepter directly:

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413765

> 18/04/2017
>
> The converted mana cost of a split card is determined by the combined mana cost of its two halves. When you activate the second ability, you may choose to cast either half of the split card, but you may not cast both halves.

It seems that the rules might have changed slightly since the Dragon's Maze expansion, and the current thinking is that you would NOT be able to imprint cards such as [Turn // Burn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369080) and [Far // Away](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369042) any more, because their CMC (for both halves) would be 5 in both instances.

Edit:

See also:

https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/amonkhet-split-card-rules-changes-2017-04-04

> Isochron Scepter can't imprint [Far // Away](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369042) or [Bound // Determined](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=107373).